# How to prevent floating menu from being clicked through to links below in IE

Tags: javascript, css, html, css-float

All the searching I've done results in questions looking to achieve the opposite.  In firefox my div layer containing a menu appears, floating above the other content when clicking another element on the page.  The content beneath such as links are not clickable.  This is the behaviour I want but it doesn't work that way in internet explorer.  In IE gaps between the links on the menu allow links on the content beneath this div to be clicked.  Also a google ad which appears below the floating div is clickable through the div.  I want the div to be solid and prevent any content underneath from being clicked in IE, could anyone help with this please?

Comment: What I have realised is that this behaviour goes away when there are scroll bars on the menu.  The 1 pixel gap that could be clicked through between the divs that make up the menu items disappears and entire google ad which could be clicked on gap or no gap is no longer clickable.  I added the scroll bars in IE using `height:expression(this.scrollHeight > 199 ? \"200px\" : \"auto\" );` as max-height does not work the way it should in IE.

Comment: The content is dynamic, when some is taken out and the scroll bars disapear the problem reocurs.  When the content is dynamically put back in and the scroll bars come back the problem is gone.

Answer (score 1):

event propagation

meaning for ex that a click traverses all elements under the cursor into deep (capturing) and back (bubbling) posiblly fireing reactions from many elements ... a common mistake is to think about graphical relation instead DOM parent-child relation (between elements)

let's experiment:

```
<div id="bottomDIV" 
onclick="rBot(event)" onMouseOver="this.style.background='olive'"
onMouseOut="this.style.background='#FF6'">bottomDIV
<div id="topDIV">topDIV</div></div>
</div>
```

so topDIV is the firstChild of BottomDIV

add some styling:

```
<style>
#bottomDIV{ width:200px;height:200px; background:#FF6;}
#topDIV{
width:200px;height:200px;
position:relative;
background:rgba(0,255,255,.5);
top:80px;left:100px;}
</style>
```

add reactions to events:

```
  <script>
//add reaction for bottomDIV
bottomDIV=document.getElementById('bottomDIV')
rBot=function(e){evt=e||event;alert(evt.type + 
            "\n"+( evt.srcElement||evt.target).id +"\n") ;//FF/IE
}


// add reactions on same event type for topDIV 
topDIV=document.getElementById('topDIV');
rTop=function(e){
        evt=e||event;
        if(evt.target)alert(evt.target.id); else alert(evt.srcElement.id)
        }

topDIV.addEventListener('click',rTop,false);
topDIV.addEventListener('mouseover',function(){this.style.background=
                                            'rgba(200,200,100,.7)'},false)
topDIV.addEventListener('mouseout',function(){this.style.background=
                                            'rgba(0,255,255,.5)'},false)
</script>
```

now observe the behaviour in booth IE/FF to click and moseover;

Even under the cursor there's no graphical overlapping of 2 divs  - to execute the topDIV reactions the event objects follows the relation parentchild and when returns fires olso the unwanted parent reactions;  So the child is the problem :)

SOLUTIONS:

**1 stop the bubbling (backflow)**

create a  crossbrowser function Stop Event Propagation

```
function SEP(evt){
                 try{evt.stopPropagation()}
                 catch(err){;evt.cancelBubble=true;}
      } //(IE/FF)
```

and rewrite every reactions of topDIV like for ex:

```
rTop=function(e){evt=e||event;SEP(evt);var elm=this;alert(elm.id);}
```

**2 - brake the relation parent-child between 2 divs** 
append topDIV directlly to the body

```
document.body.appendChild(topDIV);
```

and be sure you keep the top

```
topDIV.style.zIndex=1000;
```

EN:)     but not

I think it's a good moment to clarify .addEventListener('event', reaction , **true** ) which means the event fires at **capturing** stage

we are back before solutions 1,2 so we have a free flow of event parent-->child-->parent

what about clicking topDIV (anywhere) we fire just bottomDIV reaction ?

```
justBottomReation=function(e){evt=e||event;SEP(evt);elm=this;alert(elm.id)}
bottomDIV.addEventListener('click',justBottomReation, true)
```

this way the click is captured by the parent that will react and SEP() will block propagation to the child.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery you could use [`blockUI`](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/).

Comment: If you could create a small demo in jsfiddle it would make it easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I finally and accidentally discovered a workaround to stop IE behaving this way.  When I added a fixed width to the div containing the menu the problem with being able to click conent underneath the div disappeared.